# How to edit the Cart totals table?

Tags: custom

I like to edit the cart totals table to remove the blue arrows and the summary details from each item.
I don't know how to do this.
I like to remove those blue arrows and the tax detail rows!
[image]

Comment: Can you post more info. what is blue arrows ?

Comment: are you use default theme or else

Comment: i am using the rwd theme

Comment: Then goto `app\design\frontend\your theme\default\template\checkout\cart.phtml` find arrow and remove it